# C# String.Format - Feed in custom format

Tags: c#, string, string.format

I'm wondering if this is possible and, if so, how to accomplish it.

I know that the `String.Format` function allows you to specify a format for a parameter as follows, for example:

```
String.Format("The Date is {0:yyyy-MM-dd}", DateTime.Now);
```

But I wanted to know the best way to feed in the desired format (for exmaple "yyyy-MM-dd") to end up with a function that would work as follows (does not work, but shows what I'm trying to accomplish):

```
static string CreateFileName(string filename, string DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd")
{
    return String.Format("{0} - {1:{2}}", filename, DateTime.Now, DateTimeFormat);
}
```

I'm supposing I could put in a fake place holder and do a `String.Replace` first:

```
string formatString = "{0} - {1:{FMT}}";
formatString = formatString.Replace("{FMT}", DateTimeFormat);
```

But I'm curious to know if there is a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Thanks!!

Comment: I think you need to format your `DateTime.Now` with `DateTimeFormat` and you can specify them in `string.Format` is a different line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use:

```
var format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
var dateTimeString = string.Format("{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString(format));
```

So your function would become:

```
static string CreateFileName(string filename, string DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd")
{
    return String.Format("{0} - {1}", filename, DateTime.Now.ToString(DateTimeFormat));
}
```

Comment: @artm: Thanks for fixing my missed "

Comment: @WilliamMoore I browse SO all day looking for missing ", good to get recognition :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
static string CreateFileName(string filename, string DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd")
{
    return String.Format("{0} - {1}", filename, DateTime.Now.ToString(DateTimeFormat));
}
```

Also in **Visual Studio 2015** you can do it even simpler using the `$`.

```
static string CreateFileName(string filename, string DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd")
{
    return $"{filename} - {DateTime.Now.ToString(DateTimeFormat)}";
}
```

And even more simpler (with Expression bodies):

```
 static string CreateFileName(string filename, string DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd") 
            => $"{filename} - {DateTime.Now.ToString(DateTimeFormat)}";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, first compose format itself

```
string CreateFileName(string filename, string dateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd")
{
    var format = string.Format("\{0\} - \{1:{0}\}", dateTimeFormat);
    return string.Format(format, filename, DateTime.Now);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do

```
return String.Format(new StringBuilder("{0} - {1:").Append(DateTimeFormat).Append("}").ToString(), 
                     filename, DateTime.Now);
```

... If you want to keep it in one line.